# How to get both response JSON and headers with Got?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-got

I'm using [Got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) to make requests to a Strapi API from Node, like so:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
try {
  const request = req.query.request
  const decodedRequest = Buffer.from(request, 'base64').toString()
  const api = process.env.API_URL ? process.env.API_URL.replace(/\/$/, '') : ''

  const url = `${api}${decodedRequest}`

  const response = await got.get(url)
  const body = await got.get(url).json()
  const headers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.headers))

  res.status(200).json({
    headers: headers,
    data: body
  })
} catch (e) {
  res.status(500).json({})
}
```

This works but note that I have the request twice because if I do:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
try {
  const request = req.query.request
  const decodedRequest = Buffer.from(request, 'base64').toString()
  const api = process.env.API_URL ? process.env.API_URL.replace(/\/$/, '') : ''

  const url = `${api}${decodedRequest}`

  const response = await got.get(url)
  const body = response.json()
  const headers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.headers))

  res.status(200).json({
    headers: headers,
    data: body
  })
} catch (e) {
  res.status(500).json({
    error: e
  })
}
```

it Just crashes and the `e` from the `catch` returns an empty error so I have no idea what's going on

I need the headers because the pagination info from Strapi is returned there:

[image]

Comment: How about `const body = await response.json()`?

Comment: @Rayon the `response`in that case doesn't have a `json` method, returning a promise or otherwise.

Comment: Are you sayin `fetch(_api).then(data => data.json())` != `const res = await fetch(_api); const json = await res.json()`? @jonrsharpe

Comment: @Rayon no I'm not, but this is a different thing with a different API

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Oh yes! I misread your sentence. My bad :(
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because of the value you're awaiting. The conventional example:

```
const body = await got.get("...").json();
```

is equivalent to:

```
const res = got.get("...");
const body = await res.json();
          // ^ note
```

but **not**:

```
const res = await got.get("...");
         // ^ note
const body = res.json();
```

From the [Promise API docs](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/88056bed05ad1e601c59328bcb03ea30f5bcb4fe/documentation/1-promise.md#promise-api):

> The main Got function returns a
> [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
>
> Although in order to support cancelation,
> [`PCancelable`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-cancelable) is used
> instead of pure Promise.

The `json` method is attached to this `PCancelable` object, **not** the value it resolves to. If you try to call it on the response, therefore, you get `TypeError: res.json is not a function`.

What you want is something like:

```
const res = await got.get("...");
const body = JSON.parse(res.body);
const headers = res.headers;
// ...
```

That said, if you're doing this for pagination reasons you could also look into [their API for that](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/main/documentation/4-pagination.md).

Comment: About the pagination, it's just that in Strapi v3 at least, the info of how many pages/results and son are only present in the headers. Thank you so much!

Comment: One question, could I just return the response so I can separate in frontend? I tried changing `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'charset=utf-8')` and `res.status(200).send(response)` but is failing with error `invalid media type` any thoughts?

Comment: @Toni the error is correct, `charset=utf-8` is not itself a valid media type/`Content-Type` (it's just a _parameter_ to the type). Also you may find that the response object doesn't straightforwardly translate to JSON, which is presumably the media type you intended. It also risks exposing details to the client you shouldn't.